# Pentaho Report Designer can't find MongoDB 's collections while connecting

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer, nosql

I am using Pentaho Data Integration (PDI), for writing big data to Mongo DB.
I am going to setup the connection of my NOSQL database to Pentaho Report Designer (PRD). When I am doing that I am able to start the configuration with Host Name and port of Mongo; even PDR can find my DB.

What is the issue? PDR cannot find any collection, which is why I cannot proceed for setting up my data in the tool Report.

I don't understand why.
Anyone have an idea about that?

PDR version 5.1
Mongo 3.2.3
OS Windows